# Redirect main domain and all subdomains to non www

Tags: apache, .htaccess, cpanel

Folders structure inside `public_html`:

```
main
    index.php
subdomain1
    index.php
    .htaccess
subdomain2
    index.php
.htaccess
```

`.htaccess` in root document:

```
RewriteEngine on
#Redirect www to non www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect main domain to main folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/main/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /main/$1 [L]
```

`example.com` reads the content of `public_html/main`.

When I visit `example.com` and `www.example.com` I'm redirected to `example.com` which is correct.

`www.subdomain1.example.com` and `www.subdomain2.example.com` are not redirected to `subdomain1.example.com` and `subdomain2.example.com`.

How to fix this issue so that the subdomains redirect to non-www as well? Is there a way to do that from Apache without using `.htaccess`?

Apache version 2.4.58

I have CNAMEs for each subdomain like:

```
CNAME   www.subdomain2     subdomain2.example.com.
```

I tried to create `.htaccess` inside `subdomain2` with this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

but didn't work and shows `Your connection is not private` `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`

Comment: Do your subdomains point directly to the respective `/subdomain` subdirectory (from your file structure)? From your file structure it looks like `subdomain1` has it's own `.htaccess` file? What does this contain? Does `subdomain2` also have its own `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @MrWhite Some of the subdomains have `.htaccess` from the Laravel framework while others don't have `.htaccess`. I will update the ones having `.htaccess` but I need to get it to work with the other ones first.

Comment: _"but didn't work and shows Your connection is not private NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID"_ - for what initially requested host name? Sounds like either you did get redirected, but do not serve a valid SSL certificate for `subdomain2.example.com` - or you do not have one for `www.subdomain2.example.com`, so that it doesn't even _get_ to the point where any redirect could happen ...?